# Is it possible to expose C API in SO library to access Android JAVA methods?

Tags: android, c++, c, java-native-interface

I'm new to JAVA/Android development.
I'd like to abstract Android JAVA BLE interface and deliver higher level API in C/C++ to different team that code in javascript and is capable to call C/C++ library methods. They are working on Firefox build for different platforms and Android is the one we are working on now.

Is it possible to expose a C/C++ interface in native code (*.so library) which they can use to access JAVA methods?

I've got familiar with native code concept and it is more to be called from JAVA. It is also possible to call JAVA code from C/C++ by finding a class and a method ID but I can't understand if those C/C++ functions could be called from the external code loading the *.so library?

Is java code also required to be delivered with *.so library so it can actually call JAVA methods or is JAVA code also built into *.so file?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible in principle, but it would be something like this:

Android app has JavaScript engine that run JavaScript code, JavaScript code calls "native" method, engine calls C code (or it can be event worse and call Java code, which in turn call C code), C code calls Java code.

I don't see why you need extra steps here when you can have direct: JavaScript engine calls Java code.

Comment: We agreed on "C-like" interface that call platform native BLE methods. Such a library implement a common interface with some underlying magic platform-speciffic. In one case it's on Android, but there is also a need to port it to Win/Lin/iOS.